# Sport organisation using CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, groups

I've been asked to help setting up CiviCRM installation for local judo association. Never used the system before so if I could get some guidelines how to setup the organisation in the system I'd be grateful.

I've purchased the 2 existing books for CiviCRM and most of the functionality is clear to me. But I'm not sure how to setup the association levels.
There are nationwide admins, then local clubs, their coaches and maybe extra secretary and at the bottom regular members (adults, kids and their parents).
Should I set up each club as separate "Organisation" level type or a group?
It is essential that coaches (and whoever is assign to particular club) only see their own club members and no-one else, obviously.

I'm using Civi on top of Drupal 7, if that's any help.

Any help appreciated.

Ralph

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to civi. The approach I would recommend, having done it for several situations, is to use the [Permissioned Relationship](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) extension. This then allows you to daisy chain permissions so that local officer has a relationship to local club - and hence can see anyone how has the specified type of relationship to the club. Then you can also stack the local, regional, national (global) in the same manner, so a global officer sees everyone, the national sees everyone at or below the national level etc.

I have a diagram of this which may help explain the concept

[image: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17dlg0hIqLG7mxtCx3uakeu2dKsnBFzKOXaQPYRnmJ1Y/edit#gid=0]

So to answer the other part of the question head on, yes set up each club as an Organisation :-)

To extend that, what we have done is to then build drupal Views and Webforms which means the general club officer rarely has to actually go in to civi but get all their data, contacts etc from Views and Webforms (but that is jumping in pretty deep for a first time usage).

Happy to demo this quickly if it would help.

Comment: I would appreciate any help, if it doesn't take up too much of your time. Thanks again.

Comment: sure - you can contact me via https://www.fuzion.co.nz/contact and we can skype/hangout